# Aggregate Informations from subArray and generate a new array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my main array :

```
    array (size=25)   
18 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => 
            array (size=7)
              'prk' => int 11045323
              'lote' => int 18
              'dataCadastro' => string '2020-01-02' (length=10)
              'tipo' => string 'C' (length=1)
              'valor' => string '31.00' (length=5)
              'qtd' => int 1
              'valorTotalGlosa' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          1 => 
            array (size=7)
              'prk' => int 11145423
              'lote' => int 18
              'dataCadastro' => string '2020-01-02' (length=10)
              'tipo' => string 'C' (length=1)
              'valor' => string '15.00' (length=5)
              'qtd' => int 1
              'valorTotalGlosa' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          2 => 
            array (size=7)
              'prk' => int 11178726
              'lote' => int 18
              'dataCadastro' => string '2020-01-02' (length=10)
              'tipo' => string 'C' (length=1)
              'valor' => string '31.00' (length=5)
              'qtd' => int 1
              'valorTotalGlosa' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          3 => 
            array (size=7)
              'prk' => int 11025880
              'lote' => int 18
              'dataCadastro' => string '2020-01-02' (length=10)
              'tipo' => string 'C' (length=1)
              'valor' => string '31.00' (length=5)
              'qtd' => int 1
              'valorTotalGlosa' => string '10.00' (length=5)   
32 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=7)
              'prk' => int 12061822
              'lote' => int 32
              'dataCadastro' => string '2020-05-14' (length=10)
              'tipo' => string 'C' (length=1)
              'valor' => string '70.00' (length=5)
              'qtd' => int 1
              'valorTotalGlosa' => string '0.00' (length=4)
```

I aggregate the information this way

```
$arrLoteUnico = [];

    foreach ($lotes as $values) {
    
        $arrLoteUnico[$values['lote']][] = $values;
    
    }
```

I want to generate a new array like this, the way when have more than one info i can aggregate :

```
       array (size=7)
     0=>
          'prk' => 
              [11045323, 11178726, 11025880]
          'lote' => int 18
          'dataCadastro' => string '2020-01-02' (length=10)
          'tipo' => string 'C' (length=1)
          'valor' => (sum of the values) 31+15+31+31
          'qtd' => int 4 (1+1+1+)
          'valorTotalGlosa' => (sum of the values) 10
      1 => 
        array (size=7)
          'prk' => int 12061822
          'lote' => int 32
          'dataCadastro' => string '2020-05-14' (length=10)
          'tipo' => string 'C' (length=1)
          'valor' => string '70.00' (length=5)
          'qtd' => int 1
          'valorTotalGlosa' => string '0.00' (length=4)
```

The array which have more than one, i aggregate and display a new array with the infos.
i`m trying some things but i dont understand the logic yet to do this, want some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the first-level keys of your source array:

```php
$collection = [];

foreach ($lote as $id => $rows) {

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        
        if (!array_key_exists($id, $collection)) {

            // We haven't collected anything from the current 
            // set of rows yet. Just collect this first row
            // and skip the rest of the current loop iteration. 
            
            $collection[$id] = $row;
            continue;
        }

        // Now, we already have collected a row, so it's
        // time to aggerate the remaining ones.

        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

            if ($key == 'prk') {

                if (!is_array($collection[$id]['prk'])) {

                    $collection[$id]['prk'] = [$collection[$id]['prk']];
                }

                $collection[$id]['prk'][] = $value;
            }
            
            if (in_array($key, ['valor', 'qtd', 'valorTotalGlosa'])) {

                $collection[$id][$key] += $value;   
            }

            // ...and so on
            
        }
    }
}

var_dump($collection);
```